# When debugging at a remote location, how do we use hosts file to do that?

Tags: hosts-file

If I use `foo.my-company.com` at work, then all works well, but if we fix any bug remotely, then the web server will respond with a forbidden.

I heard we can use `dev1-foo.my-company.com` at a remote location, and it is the same site, but if I access that, I found that all the AJAX are still done to `foo.my-company.com` and it won't work because it is still forbidden.  It seems that "hosts file" can be used to overcome this, but how specifically?

Answer (score 2):

All a hosts file can do is associate a hostname (like dev1-foo.my-company.com) to an IP address (like 10.1.1.5).

This can be enormously useful if:

- Your DNS doesn't have an entry for the host you need (e.g. "dev1")

  ... or ..
- You want to *override* DNS (substitute your own "dev1", e.g. for testing)

This is all TCP/IP - it has nothing directly to do with higher-level protocols like HTTP or AJAX.

'Hope that helps ..

Comment: specifically, should I `ping dev1-foo.my-company.com` and find the IP address, let's say it is `123.12.34.56`, then add the line  `123.12.34.56 foo.my-company.com` to hosts file?  Also, I can only ping it to find out the IP -- I cannot `nslookup` to find it.

Comment: To clarify: `forbidden` is a HTTP response, unrelated to TCP/IP and therefore not fixable at that level. Either you misunderstood your source, or they were wrong.

Comment: actually, if I do what I said in the comment, everything works perfectly.  But I am just trying to see why `nslookup` didn't work and find out what I don't know about hosts file.

Comment: if you can "ping dev1-foo.my-company.com" and it gives you an IP address ... then you are *ALREADY* resolving the hostname to an IP address, and you *DO NOT NEED* to add anything to /etc/hosts.

Comment: nslookup can fail for many different reasons.  Perhaps the first question I'd ask: Are you running nslookup on Windows or Linux (or "something else")?  Is your DNS infrastructure on Windows or Linux?  I would encourage you to google for "nslookup troubleshooting" or "nslookup fails".  I would also encourage you to post on http://serverfault.com, which is better suited for questions like this than SO.  IMHO..

Comment: actually, wouldn't it be, even if I can ping, then it can still give me an Access Denied?  For example, I can still get something back, hence the ping works, but the "something" is the content that it is access denied?

Comment: Yes: even if you can ping, you can still get an "Access Denied".  MSalters said it best: "To clarify: forbidden is a HTTP response, unrelated to TCP/IP and therefore not fixable at that level."  Whether or not you can ping, whether you use DNS or /etc/hosts, whether or not nslookup works: *ALL* of these are unrelated to the "forbidden" HTTP response.